# Laravel - General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I try to save or update a model, I get an error that is below, for the field spid_id. I am not sure what is wrong.

> General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'spid_id'
>   at row 1 (SQL: update `magazines` set `spid_id` = , `updated_at` =
>   2016-10-21 08:28:46, `summary` = where `id` = 8)

This is how my table looks:

```
       Schema::create('magazines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('visual_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('spid_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I tried to change my spid_id to not be nullable in the DB, by making a migration, because I thought that might be a reason:

```
        Schema::table('magazines', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('spid_id')->change();
        });
```

But the field still remained nullable.

This is my store function for create form:

```
        $magazine = Magazine::create([
          'name' => $request->input('name'),
          'visio_link_prefix' => $request->input('visio_link_prefix'),
          'spid_id' => $request->input('spid_id'),
          'summary' => $request->input('summary'),
        ]);
```

Comment: Show us  the place where you updateing in Laravel

Comment: If the value is blank then dont set the key. It will try to save the data as integer (without `'`s). Or add quotes around the value or filter the array.

Comment: Could you please post code where the error happens. So code updating or saving model?

Comment: I did, you can see the store function, this where it is happening

Comment: Can you try `'spid_id' => $request->has('spid_id') ? $request->input('spid_id') : NULL,`?

Comment: can you dd($request->input('spid_id')) ? What is the output?

Comment: yes, that did the trick @aleksejjj

Comment: @Marco Good. I'll post this as an answer. It may be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check `spid_id` exist in your request before you save it. For example in your case it will looks like:

```
'spid_id' => $request->has('spid_id') ? $request->input('spid_id') : NULL,
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to create a record is by using eloquent objects

```
    $magazine = new Magazine
    $magazine->name = $request->input('name');
    $magazine->visio_link_prefix = $request->input('visio_link_prefix')
    $magazine->spid_id = $request->input('spid_id', null);
    $magazine->summary = $request->input('summary');
    $magazine->save();
```

This will make sure it automatically assign a null or default value which you may have specified in your model.